Showing $\operatorname{Tr}\left(I-\frac{1}{\|A\|^2}A^TA\right)\ge\operatorname{Tr}\prod_i \left(I-\frac{1}{\|a_i\|^2}a_i^T a_i\right)$
Suppose $a_i$ is the $i$th row of real-valued matrix $A$ and $\|A\|$ is operator norm. Is the following true for all $A$? (it appears so in simulations)
$$\operatorname{Tr}\left(I-\frac{1}{\|A\|^2}A^TA\right)\ge\operatorname{Tr}\prod_i \left(I-\frac{1}{\|a_i\|^2}a_i^T a_i\right)$$
Motivation: this is a weaker version of a noncommutative arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, which has been proposed but shown not to hold in general.
Notebook

Can you reduce to triangular matrices via QR and then apply induction to remove the single element?

Do you assume $A$ to be square or wide? Otherwise the statement does not hold for [[1,1],[1,1],[1,0]].

@AndreiSmolensky no restrictions. I plugged in your example and got 0.904>=0.5

@YaroslavBulatov Indeed, made a stupid mistake in my code.

@YaroslavBulatov the proof I provided assumes $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a square matrix and $|\boldsymbol{A}|$ represents Frobenius norm. If these assumptions are suitable for your context, you may want to update your question with these assumptions to bring closure to this thread :)

@user407223 assuming square is fine (since can always pad rectangular matrix with 0s), but using Frobenius norm instead of operator norm makes the problem different. It corresponds to analyzing gradient descent in $d$ dimensions using $1/d$ learning rate (Frobenius) rather than $1/\sqrt{d}$ learning rate (operator norm)

I believe the inequality is false. The matrix $A$ is chosen to be $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \cos(2\pi/5) & \sin(2\pi/5) \\ \cos(4\pi/5) & \sin(4\pi/5) \\ \cos(6\pi/5) & \sin(6\pi/5) \\ \cos(8\pi/5) & \sin(8\pi/5) \end{bmatrix}$.
By symmetry, the matrix $A^\top A$ is a multiple of $I$. Thus, the LHS is $0$. The RHS evaluates to $\approx 0.0028178107$.

Thanks, good point. Looks like any tall matrix with mutually orthogonal columns works as a counter-example here. Chris Re pointed me to another counter-example described in Section 5 of Random Reshuffling is Not Always Better, where

If we assume that $\boldsymbol{A}$ is a square matrix of size $n\times n$ and let $\|\boldsymbol{A}\|$ represent the Frobenius norm instead of spectral norm, then here is a proof. Following your convention $\boldsymbol{a}_i$'s are row vectors.
The left side can be simplified as:
\begin{equation}
Tr(\boldsymbol{I}-\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{A}\|^2} \boldsymbol{A}^T \boldsymbol{A}) = Tr(\boldsymbol{I})-\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{A}\|^2} Tr(\boldsymbol{A}^T \boldsymbol{A}) = Tr(\boldsymbol{I})-\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{A}\|^2} \|\boldsymbol{A}\|^2 = n- 1
\end{equation}
Now we get to the right hand side. For brevity, let $\boldsymbol{X}_i = \boldsymbol{I}-\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{a}_i\|^2} \boldsymbol{a}_i^T \boldsymbol{a}_i$. Observe that for each $\boldsymbol{X}_i$, n-1 eigenvalues are 1 and the n'th eigenvalue is 0. Thus, for any $n \geq 1$ , ${\boldsymbol{X}_i}^n=\boldsymbol{X}_i$ and also $Tr(\boldsymbol{X}_i)=n-1$. Putting these together yields $(Tr({\boldsymbol{X}_i}^n))^{\frac{1}{n}} = (n-1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and thus $\Pi_{i=1}^n (Tr({\boldsymbol{X}_i}^n))^{\frac{1}{n}} = n-1$.
Since $\boldsymbol{X}_i$'s are PSD, we can use Holder's inequality for Trace [1]: $Tr(\Pi_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol{X}_i) \leq \Pi_{i=1}^n (Tr({\boldsymbol{X}_i}^n))^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Combining with last result yields $Tr(\Pi_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol{X}_i) \leq n-1$. Recall from the beginning that $Tr(\boldsymbol{I}-\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{A}\|^2} \boldsymbol{A}^T \boldsymbol{A}) = n-1$. Thus $Tr(\Pi_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol{X}_i) \leq Tr(\boldsymbol{I}-\frac{1}{\|\boldsymbol{A}\|^2} \boldsymbol{A}^T \boldsymbol{A})$.
[1] https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11117-006-2054-6

In the first chain if equalities you use $|A|$ for the Frobenius norm, while the author meant the spectral norm.

Thanks @AndreiSmolensky. I added a note to my answer that the proof is for when $|\boldsymbol{A}|$ represents the Frobenius norm.

No, $Tr(A^TA) \ne \|A\|^2.$ Assume that $A$ is square and has an SVD $A = USV^T$, where $S=\mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n)$, and $\sigma_1 \geq \ldots \geq \sigma_n \geq 0$ are the singular values. Then $Tr(A^TA)=\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2$ but $\|A\|^2 = \sigma_1^2$.
It is easy to show that $Tr(I-\frac{1}{\|A\|^2}A^TA) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{\sigma_k^2}{\sigma_1^2}\right)$. The issue is how to connect the RHS with the singular values of $A$.
